# Same level divs

Tags: css, xhtml, blueprint-css

I use Blueprint CSS framework to style my site. I have this code:

```
<div class="span-10">
        <div class="span-5">
            <img alt="" src="system/images/picabu1.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="span-5 last">
            Lorem ipsum sup dolor itaseum.. <br />
            <img alt="" src="system/images/addtobasket.jpg" />
        </div>
</div>
```

When there is a lot of text at div `span-5 last` image (addtobasket.jpg) descends down.
How can I make at same level images (picabu1.png and addtobasket.jpg)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think only

```
<div class="span-10">
        <!-- text elements first -->
        <div class="span-5">
        </div>
        <div class="span-5 last">
            Lorem ipsum sup dolor itaseum.. <br />
        </div>
        <!-- images elements follow -->
        <div class="span-5">
            <img alt="" src="system/images/picabu1.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="span-5 last">
            <img alt="" src="system/images/addtobasket.jpg" />
        </div>
</div>
```

will achieve this.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/xSmmA/